# navigate the resultset using forward and backward

Tags: java, sql

In java if we want to navigate the resultset which we get from executing the query using 2 buttons forward and backward. What is the way we can perform this task

```
    private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        if(evt.getSource()==bt_previous){
        DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
             try {
                        Connection con = util.getConnection();
                        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DETAILS where id=?");
                        ResultSet rs;
                        String rm = id.getText().trim();
                        stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(rm));
                        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                        while(rs.next()){

                        String a = rs.getString("weight");
                        txtboxwgt.setText(a);
                        String b = rs.getString("note_state");
                        cbnotstat.setSelectedItem(b);
                        String c = rs.getString("dm_state");
                        cbdmnstat.setSelectedItem(c);
                                      }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                         }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an entity class `Detail`:

```
public class Detail {
    private String weight;
    private String noteState;
    private String dmState;

    public Detail() {

    }

    public Detail(String weight, String noteState, String dmState) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.noteState = noteState;
        this.dmState = dmState;
    }
    // getters and setters below
}
```

In your `nextActionPerformed` method when you iterate over the result set, create a new instance of your entity and add it to some collection, i.e. `LinkedList`:

```
                List<Detail> allDetails = new LinkedList<Detail>();
                while(rs.next()) {

                    String a = rs.getString("weight");
                    String b = rs.getString("note_state");
                    String c = rs.getString("dm_state");
                    allDetail.add(new Detail (a, b, c));
                }
```

Then you can navigate the `allDetails` in any manner supported by the  `LinkedList`. Or consider using another collection if LinkedList doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to paginate your result.
AFAIK there is no easy task to be done with the result set, no built in feature.
You have the following options:

1. Transform each row intro an object and actually display the objects. Keep lists of the pages displayed so far and provide them as needed (for back move) and use the result set for forward. This, however, has its limitations: if you have plenty of objects it is possible you will reach the limit of system's memory, thus it is not recommended unless you know there is a small amount of objects.
2. Paginate using an additional database table.
   For this create an additional table with the structure: `page`, `item_id`. Name it `history_table`. Then read the first 50 objects (assuming you want to show 50 rows at a time). That is page 1. Insert the unique identifiers in the history table, along with the page number.
   When needed to go backwards, read the unique ids from the previous page. When going forward, execute the select.

The sql statement for going forward would look like this:

```
select * from my_table a where not exists (select 1 from history_table h where a.item_id = h.item_id)
```

This you execute for every page required (even the first one!)

Inserting the previous read elements in the database should be done using [batch insert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm#CHDCCEHD).